# Subscribing to a YouTube channel via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, youtube-api

so I am really frustrated because I am trying to post this to the YouTube api.
However, when I use Ajax, I get the syntax unexpected t variable error.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
url:"gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/subscriptions",
type:"POST",
data:"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'          xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
<category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/subscriptiontypes.cat'
term='channel'/>
<yt:username>GoogleDevelopers</yt:username>
</entry>",
Authorization: token,
GData-Version: '2',
X-GData-Key:     'key=MYDEVKEY',
contentType:"application/atom+xml",
dataType:"xml",
success: function(){
alert('subscribd');
}
});
```

And with some research, I found that the first line of the code causes the error. Is there any way to posting that data to the api. Oh and the documentation a is at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_subscriptions#Adding_a_subscription. Please can I have some help on how to post this data? Thanks!

Comment: Is that a multiline string in JavaScript?

Comment: @Mohsen, removed spaces, and still the same error!

Comment: Write the whole XML thing in one line. JS doesn't have multiline string.

Comment: @mohsen yes I have tried that. The problem is that <?xml...?> is causing the problem. And if I remove that line, the XML is invalid.

Comment: replace your line breaks with `\n`. `<?xml...?>\n<entry...` is valid string and valid XML

Comment: no, I still get unexpected T_STRING....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to avoid doing this using the YouTUbe GData API v2. While it's certainly possible to get this to work, it relies on your JavaScript running in a browser that supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), and  that rules out all but the most recent versions of Internet Explorer.

If you do want to do this using the GData API v2, you will probably find it easier to POST with a JSON body instead of an XML body, and include `alt=json` in the POST URL. There's an example of making POST requests with JSON bodies against v2 [here](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/source/browse/static/js/ytdl/utils.js?spec=svnd80933123179ecf600b74220b15f8bb42c606aa5&r=d80933123179ecf600b74220b15f8bb42c606aa5#342), as well as other examples floating around.

What I'd really recommend doing, though, is using the YouTube Data API v3, which has a [subscriptions.insert()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert) method for adding subscriptions. There's a great JavaScript [client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/) you could use which will take care of handling OAuth 2 for you, as well as making the API requests in a way that works across a wide range of browsers.